# How to load scripts and styles directly for TinyMCE popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I’m creating a Wordpress Plugin in which I’ve created a ‘Shortcode Generator’ using the TinyMCE popup window, that I see in a lot of the plugins. The problem is that, since TinyMCE uses an iframe to create that popup window, I can’t find a way to use wp_enqueue_style() and wp_enqueue_script() to load css and js files specifically for that window.

Right now I’m using the `<script>` and `<link>` tags for that, which of course is not allowed in the the Theme submission requirements.

I would really like to know if I’m ok to use it here, as I really don’t find any other way with which this can be done.

Here is what I am doing

```
function ava_test_init() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'sbb-test-js', plugins_url( '/js/jquery.js', __FILE__ ));
     wp_enqueue_script( 'sbb-js', plugins_url( '/js/tiny_mce_popup.js', __FILE__ ));
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','ava_test_init');
```

But It's not working.
Thanks!

Comment: I just checked how WooCommerce adds the Shortcode Generator popups, and it seems that the popup window is not in an iframe, only the editor window is. So, can you give more details about your case?

Comment: @masa As I'm using Tinymice popup Loading popup on button click. So JS should be loaded on popup window. As its not possible using wp_enqueue_script. I'm uploading Plugin file. Where sbb_popup.php is being opened on button click. On that file I've added two JS file, jquery.js and tiny_mce_popup.js.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3CGVSjmOpnyby1IZjlRTWVaZ0k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I would not use an iframe for the dialog content, unless there is a good reason to do so (is there?). Just because using iframes is always more complicated and also slows down the UI (as can be seen also here, when comparing with WC SG popups). Can you consider changing that part (use the WC SG plugin as a guideline)? If yes, then I guess your problem has a simple solution.